# Boolean function

Tags: modeling, modifiers

So I am following a tutorial and the person who is explaining is using his own custom keys and pie menus and at one moment he is using 'Boolean add' which isn't a function in normal blender menu and I can't reproduce the thing he is doing.

Explanation of the pics: He is adding extra geometry with those planes in order to make it easier to use lattice and deform it, so he criss-crossing the planes he created with the object and then use the 'boolean add' on his pie menu and the object has extra geometry to work with and he even deletes what was left from the planes after that and everything works fine.

I will really appreciated any kind of help, I am pretty new to this so I hope I explained it well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of the question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: the boolean add isnt a function in the menus, its a modifier that you can add from the modifiers tab on one object, then select a second object that you want to merge it with.

Comment: Yes I am aware it's not in the menus in the default settings , he has this 'boolean add' in his custom pie menu and when I try all the functions with the boolean modifier , not one of them get me the results he gets when he uses his custom 'boolean add'.

Comment: Solved, so it was actually the kinfe(intersect) in face mode.